# Unable to insert data in database in java after adding current date time logic

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database, jsp

I have following code

query is

```
insert into discussions(title,description,usrid,date,uuid,rty,yu,visit) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Java code is

```
java.util.Date utilDate=new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date date=new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());

ps.setString(1,t.getTitle()); //ps is prepared statement object,
ps.setString(2,t.getDescription());
ps.setString(3,t.getUsrID());
ps.setDate(4,date);
ps.setString(5,getUniqueID(usrType));
ps.setLong(6,Long.valueOf(t.getRty())); //t.getRty() is String and parsed to set a Bigint in database
ps.setLong(7,Long.valueOf(t.getyu())); //t.getyu() is String and parsed to set a Bigint in database
ps.setLong(8,Long.valueOf(t.getVisit())); //t.geVisit() is String and parsed to set a Bigint in database
```

When I added the code for getting current date as show above all 'ps' statements. The code is giving SQLException as ***com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 6 is out of range.***

It was working fine when I inserted date as string. But I need date in Date format because of sorting issue.
Please tell me whats wrong??

Comment: What's the type of the field in the database?

Comment: title, description and usrid are nvarchar(max), date is DateTime, uuid is String, rty, yu and visit are bigint

Comment: Hmm... Are you *sure* you're using that query? I'd really expect that to work. Check that you haven't got a reference to the wrong SQL statement for some reason.

Comment: Ya I am using the same query and it worked when I inserted date as String type but when I replaced the datatype of date with Date, it is showing the error

Answer (score 0):

what happens when you convert the `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` inside the `setDate()`

```
    String date = request.getParameter("date");//get the requested String
Date utilDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(date);//format using java.util.Date

ps.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime()));//insert
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the date format which you are using to insert in `MS SQL`. It seems that you are trying to insert date in some other format than what `MS SQL` expects.
I don not have much experience which default date format `MS SQL` is using.

Check that and converting your date in that format should work.